# How to debug with LD_preload

Tags: c, debugging, mpi, ld, ld-preload

I use LD_PRELOAD to override the MPI_Send function with my own function to do some debugging of the MPI_send function.

Here, myMPI_Send.c code:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int MPI_Send(const void *buf, int count, MPI_Datatype datatype, int dest, int tag, MPI_Comm comm)
{
        int (*original_MPI_Send)(const void *, int, MPI_Datatype, int, int, MPI_Comm);    
        original_MPI_Send=dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "MPI_Send");    
        printf(" Calling MPI_Send ************** \n");    
        return (*original_MPI_Send)(buf, count, datatype, dest, tag, comm);
}
```

In my project, I use an extern library which includes also MPI_Send functions. I need to debug the extern library to know the line and the number of calls of each call of MPI_Send.

I tried to use this code using macros:

```
fprintf (stderr,"MPI_Send, func <%s>, file %s, line %d, count %d\n",__func__, __FILE__, __LINE__, __COUNTER__);
```

But, it doesn't work, it prints always the line of MPI_Send in the myMPI_Send.so.

Could you help me please? Thank you in advance.

Comment: `__func__` and `__FILE__` are replaced by the compiler with a const strings representing the function and file respectively. In this case, both are part of `myMPI_send.c`, which is what is printed.

Comment: What you need to do is change the declaration of `MPI_Send` to also pass `char *caller_func, char *caller_file`, which you can print here. Then you need to edit every caller to this function in order to add `__func__` and `__FILE__`. Otherwise, the binary will not contain the information required to retrieve this information.

Comment: Thank you for your response. if I change MPI_Send, I should change it in the external library also, but for me I cannnot change the code of the external library

Comment: If you just want a list of callers, maybe its easier to run the program with `gdb`. Then you can put a breakpoint on `MPI_Send` and set a command on the breakpoint to print a backtrace. The breakpoint will identify the caller. You can also shorten the backtrace to only include `MPI_Send` and the caller using the command `bt 2` (https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Backtrace.html).

Comment: If you know how to parse debugging (DWARF) information, you might be able to read the caller's address (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-12.2.0/gcc/Return-Address.html) and then link that to a file and line number. However, I envision that this is fairly complicated, since I have never directly worked with debug info.

Comment: Debugging MPI applications in parallel with gdb, is not the best solution I think..

Comment: I'd suggest using the second method I suggested then. Dump the return address, which will indirectly identify the caller. Then, either online or offline, convert that return address to a file and function.

Answer (score 1):

MPI covers most of your needs via the MPI Profiling Interface (aka PMPI).

Simply redifines the `MPI_*` subroutines you need, and have them call the original `PMPI_*` corresponding subroutine.

In you case:

```
int MPI_Send(const void *buf, int count, MPI_Datatype datatype, int dest, int tag, MPI_Comm comm)
{
        printf(" Calling MPI_Send ************** \n");    
        PMPI_Send(buf, count, datatype, dest, tag, comm);
}
```

Since you want to print the line and file of the caller, you might have to use macros and rebuild your app:

```
#define MPI_Send(buf,count,MPI_Datatype, dest, tag, comm) \
    myMPI_Send(buf, count, MPI_Datatype, dest, tag, comm, __func__, __FILE__, __LINE__)

int myMPI_Send(const void *buf, int count, MPI_Datatype datatype, int dest, int tag, MPI_Comm comm, char *func, char *file, int line)
{
        printf(" Calling MPI_Send ************** from %s at %s:%d\n", func, file, line);    
        return PMPI_Send(buf, count, datatype, dest, tag, comm);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reponse. I have modified "myMPI_Send.c code:" to print the line and file of the caller as you suggested in the second code above. But, It doesn't work for me , It prints nothing!! It seems correct but I didn't find the problem!

Comment: Did you recompile **all** your code?

Comment: Yes, I did. But, just to be sure.  I modified  the "myMPI_Send.c"  and added the second code.                                                                                                                                                         and then I  used LD_PRELOAD to load the shared library, and then recompile my code. Is this correct?

Comment: `#define MPI_Send ...` should be in the original code for this to work ... but I realized that would defeat the purpose of `LD_PRELOAD`! Maybe you can simply `#define MPI_Send(...) MPI_Send(..., __func__, __FILE__, __LINE__)` in your original code and redefine `MPI_Send()` that calls `PMPI_Send()` in the library you will preload.

Comment: Otherwise use `libunwind` or similar to get the address where `MPI_Send()` is called, and convert that later with (for example) `addr2line`.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Okay I will try libunwind. I found also __builtin_return_address (unsigned int level). It prints the adress.. In my case, the command that I use to run my MPI application  is : >python3 run.py --np 2, the addr2line needs a filename, but when I use: >  addr2line -e  run.py  "adress" --> it doesn't work and I get this message: >addr2line: « run.py »: no such file !!

Comment: I also trry to use this command: >addr2line -j .text -e /projets/mylib.so 0x7fab9d24d156                                                      but I get this result: ??:0, It doesn't print the file of caller!

Comment: I guess the caller is your program, so you should not run `addr2line` on `mylib.so`. But since you use `python`, the caller is either the dynamic library used by `mpi4py` or the python interpreter, so that will not help you much...